# Delete the last item element JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm working on something, basically I have this Add Parameter button which adds 2 new text field namely a parameter name and parameter value. I have a button which is delete parameter. How can I delete the last parameter name and value? The button should delete the last.

Here's my code https://jsfiddle.net/q7fokdbw/

```
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5" id="paramArea">
  </div>

 </div>

<div class="form-group">
<div class="col-sm-10">
   <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="paramCount" name="paramCount" />
  </div>
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addParams">Add Parameter</button>
      </div>
  </div>

 <div class="form-group">
     <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
         <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="deleteParams">Detele Parameter</button>
      </div>
 </div>

<script>
$(function() {
var count = 0;
$( "#addParams" ).click(function() {
    $("#paramArea").append('<br /><input type=text class="form-control" name=ParamName'+count+' id=ParamName'+count+' placeholder="Parameter Name" /> '); 
    $("#paramArea").append('<br /><input type=text class="form-control" name=ParamValue'+count+' id=ParamValue'+count+' placeholder="Parameter Value" />'); 

    count++;

    $("#paramCount").val(count);

});


});

  </script>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should rather wrap those two inputs in div and append it to `#paramArea`. like this:

```
$("#paramArea").append('
   <div class="rowelement"><input type=text class="form-control" name=ParamName'+count+' 
   id=ParamName'+count+' placeholder="Parameter Name" /><br />
   <input type=text class="form-control" 
   name=ParamValue'+count+' id=ParamValue'+count+'placeholder="Parameter Value" /></div>
');
```

and on click of delete button, you can get `.rowelement` and delete last element using `:last` and `.remove()`

```
$("#deleteParams").click(function(){
    $(".rowelement:last").remove();
});
```

Comment: I hope I could select other's as well but this works for me thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use `.remove()` with the `:last` selector

```
$('#deleteParams').click(function(){
    $('[id^=ParamName]:last,[id^=ParamValue]:last').remove();
});
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q7fokdbw/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

You can do it something like :

```
$("#deleteParams").on('click', function(){
    $("#paramArea").find(':text:last').remove();
});
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/q7fokdbw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Using a container will make this easier.

```js
$(function() {
  var count = 0;
  $("#addParams").click(function() {
    $("#paramArea").append(
      '<br /><div class="container"><input type=text class="form-control" name=ParamName' + count + ' id=ParamName' + count + ' placeholder="Parameter Name" /> <br /><input type=text class="form-control" name=ParamValue' + count + ' id=ParamValue' + count + ' placeholder="Parameter Value" /></div>');

    count++;

    $("#paramCount").val(count);

  });

  $("#deleteParams").click(function() {
    $('.container').last().remove();
  });


});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-5" id="paramArea">
  </div>

</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="paramCount" name="paramCount" />
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="addParams">Add Parameter</button>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="deleteParams">Detele Parameter</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
$("#deleteParams" ).click(function() {
         $("#paramArea").find(".form-control").filter( ":last" ).remove();
});
```